# Array of Strings won't properly output to file (Java)

Tags: java, file, io, output

I've made an algorithm that alphabetically sorts a text file of names into an array, as it stands, the sorted array is around 21'000 names long. It outputs to the console fine (I used a delayed output due to the fact that the console cuts out after a while), but when I try to output to a file it stops 2 thirds into the array, around the letter "T".

Any suggestions? Here is my output code:

```
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("E:\\output.txt"));

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        System.out.println(names[i]);
        bw.write(names[i]);
        bw.newLine();}
```

I have also tried to output starting from the end of the array

```
for (int i = names.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        System.out.println(names[i]);
        bw.write(names[i]);
        bw.newLine();}
```

In this case the array stops outputting to the file around the letter "B".
I thought maybe there was an overflow or something outputting to the file, but even adding a delay to each loop still yielded the same result.

Comment: You're likely not closing your Writer after use.

Comment: Please see this [link to one way to search your topic before asking](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+buffereredwriter+not+writing+full+file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a "try with resources" to guarantee that your writer will be closed.
Or if you do not want to close it at the moment, call the "flush" method.

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("E:\\output.txt"))) {

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
        System.out.println(names[i]);
        bw.write(names[i]);
        bw.newLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Answering what is quite likely a duplicate